# How to check if the browser is fully loaded?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I have created an app that interacts with the Android Emulator via ADB which takes a few touches to a new url

Everything is working fine, however for now I'm just doing time.sleep() for 15 seconds to make sure the browser has finished loading the URL. in some cases the browser finished loading before 15 seconds and sometimes after 15 seconds

I want a way to check if it's finished loading

Comment: If you have control on the app source code you could enable remote debugging by calling `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)`  on the webvview. The you should be able to get even detailed information about the webview and what it displays. I am not sure if there are command-line tools available for PC side or third party implementations of the protocol but that would be a generic approach to test if the the app is running and the webview has loaded the page.